# How to hide/show links (elements) using JavaScript on multiple pages having same id in respective pages?

Tags: javascript, show-hide

I want to `hide/show` elements in result of `login/logout`. Multile pages have same element with same ids which I wants to access in login/logout function to hide or show. I have used `style.display` property which is not working for elements of any page. How to do it properly. Kindly have a look on my code. Thank you!

```js
var objPeople=[
];

var userAccName;


function checkLogin()
{

      var x=document.getElementById("displayReg");
      var y=document.getElementById("displayLogin");
      var z=document.getElementById("displayLogout");
      x.style.display = "none";
      y.style.display = "none";
      z.style.display = "block";
      console.log("xxxxxxxxxxxx",x,y,z)
   window.open("index.html");
  }
function signUp()
{
 var x=document.getElementById("displayReg");
      var y=document.getElementById("displayLogin");
      var z=document.getElementById("displayLogout");
      x.style.display = "none";
      y.style.display = "none";
      z.style.display = "block";
      console.log("xxxxxxxxxxxx",x,y,z)
   window.open("index.html");
}


function logout()
{
 var x=document.getElementById("displayReg");
      var y=document.getElementById("displayLogin");
      var z=document.getElementById("displayLogout");
      x.style.display = "block";
      y.style.display = "block";
      z.style.display = "none";
      console.log("xxxxxxxxxxxx",x,y,z)
   window.open("index.html");

}
```

```html
<!-- index page -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
      <title>Index</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
      
  </head>
  
  <body class="productPage">  
  
  <header id="aa-header">
      <div class="aa-header-top">
     
            <div class="aa-header-top-area">
              <!-- start header top left -->
              <div class="aa-header-top-left">
                
              </div>
              <!-- / header top left -->
               <div class="aa-header-top-right">
                <ul class="aa-head-top-nav-right">
                  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                  <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="#" onclick="checkoutBtn()">Checkout</a></li>
                  <li id="displayReg"><a href="registration.html">Register</a></li>
                  <li id="displayReg"><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
                  <li id="displayLogout" class="hidden-xs" style="display: none;" ><a href="#" onclick="logout()">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- / header bottom  -->
</header>


   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


  
    <script src="js/account.js"></script>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script>  

  </body>
</html>


<!-- login page -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
      <title>Login</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
      
  </head>
  
  <body class="productPage">  
  
  <header id="aa-header">
      <div class="aa-header-top">
     
            <div class="aa-header-top-area">
              <!-- start header top left -->
              <div class="aa-header-top-left">
                
              </div>
              <!-- / header top left -->
               <div class="aa-header-top-right">
                <ul class="aa-head-top-nav-right">
                  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                  <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="#" onclick="checkoutBtn()">Checkout</a></li>
                  <li id="displayReg"><a href="registration.html">Register</a></li>
                  <li id="displayLogin"><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
                  <li id="displayLogout" class="hidden-xs" style="display: none;" ><a href="#" onclick="logout()">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- / header bottom  -->
</header>

<button onclick="checkLogin()">login</button>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


  
    <script src="js/account.js"></script>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script>  

  </body>
</html>

<!-- reg page -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
      <title>Register</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
      
  </head>
  
  <body class="productPage">  
  
  <header id="aa-header">
      <div class="aa-header-top">
     
            <div class="aa-header-top-area">
              <!-- start header top left -->
              <div class="aa-header-top-left">
                
              </div>
              <!-- / header top left -->
               <div class="aa-header-top-right">
                <ul class="aa-head-top-nav-right">
                  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                  <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="#" onclick="checkoutBtn()">Checkout</a></li>
                  <li id="displayReg"><a href="registration.html">Register</a></li>
                  <li id="displayReg"><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
                  <li id="displayLogout" class="hidden-xs" style="display: none;" ><a href="#" onclick="logout()">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- / header bottom  -->
</header>
<button onclick="signUp()">Register</button>


   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


  
    <script src="js/account.js"></script>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script>  

  </body>
</html>
<!-- contact page -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
      <title>Contact</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
      
  </head>
  
  <body class="productPage">  
  
  <header id="aa-header">
      <div class="aa-header-top">
     
            <div class="aa-header-top-area">
              <!-- start header top left -->
              <div class="aa-header-top-left">
                
              </div>
              <!-- / header top left -->
               <div class="aa-header-top-right">
                <ul class="aa-head-top-nav-right">
                  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                  <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="#" onclick="checkoutBtn()">Checkout</a></li>
                  <li id="displayReg"><a href="registration.html">Register</a></li>
                  <li id="displayReg"><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
                  <li id="displayLogout" class="hidden-xs" style="display: none;" ><a href="#" onclick="logout()">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- / header bottom  -->
</header>


   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


  
    <script src="js/account.js"></script>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script>  

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When selecting an element with `document.getElementById ("_id")` it is always the first element with that `_id` that is being returned. That is why only the first `<li>` becomes hidden.

It is a bad thing to have multiple items with the same `id`.

Instead:

Add a common data type attribute instead of a common id.

```
<li data-id="displayReg"><a href="registration.html">Register</a></
<li data-id="displayReg"><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
```

And in javascript you can select these elements by doing:

```
var _elements = document.querySelectorAll ("[data-id = 'displayReg']");
```

Now `_elements` is a NodeList containing the 2 `<li>` s.

Finally you can iterate through that NodeList and hide each element:

```
_elements.forEach( 
   function(e) { 
        e.style.display = "none"; 
}
```